# Can't start video. Try closing other programs that might be using your webcam

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, skype

My webcam doesn't work, I installed the camera driver.
Camera option in Skype:

[image]
[image]

I closed all programs but camera not work

Comment: Do a quick check: go [here](http://www.cameroid.com/snap.php), tell me if you can use your camera there.

Comment: @matan129 no, doesn't work http://i.imgur.com/7VGUYq3.png

Comment: OK, that means the problem isn't with Skype only. Try updating the webcam drivers.

Comment: What camera? Has this worked before, or is this the first time attempting to use it?

Comment: @matan129 I think I changed the firmware for webcam. When I delete the device and reinstall driver nothig changed

Comment: @Luke camera is inside notebook above Display. After I changed the firmware, the camera doesn't work

Comment: It's kind of trivial, bit have you tried simply restarting your computer? It usually help with such things. If the problem isn't resolved after restart try again re-installing the driver.

Comment: @matan129 I tried 10 or more reinstall and restarting computer

Comment: Exactly which make/model of the notebook? What's the make/model of the embedded camera?  Exactly which Firmware did you flash?

Comment: @techie007 notebook msi ex623 , with tool Chicony Firmware Tool v.3.0.2 -, firmware update CKF7010 firmware 6322. How set firmware by default?

Comment: Unless you're SURE it's a Chicony webcam, I'd be concerned you flashed the firmware of the wrong camera and now you've got [a brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_(electronics)) instead of a webcam.  Notebook manufactures often use more than one webcam vendor in the same model (line).

Comment: @techie007 You know how uninstall this firmware?

Comment: I posted my last comment and an answer to this comment in an actual answer.  It's probably not what you want to hear, but I think it's what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're SURE it's a Chicony webcam, I'd be concerned you flashed the firmware of the wrong camera and now you've got [a brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29) instead of a webcam. Notebook manufactures often use more than one webcam vendor in the same model (line).

Firmware is a one-way street, there's no way to uninstall or remove firmware.  You *might* be able to flash the proper firmware over-top, but usually once you flash the wrong firmware, the device is done-for (as there's then no way to communicate with the hardware to flash the 'right' firmware).

Although I suspect it may be too late, you can figure out which webcam hardware your notebook manufacturer used, and then in turn figure out what firmware/drivers you need by following a guide like this TechSpot one: [How to identify your webcam (and then find its driver)](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/how-to-identify-your-webcam-and-then-find-its-driver.123880/).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is WAY late, but if what Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 postulates is accurate, namely that the camera is now a 'brick' due to having been flashed with incorrect firmware, the first place to try in searching for the correct firmware would be from the manufacturer's website.

Note: The question poster stated in comments "I think I changed the firmware for webcam" and when Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 asked "Exactly which make/model of the notebook? What's the make/model of the embedded camera? Exactly which Firmware did you flash?" they replied with "notebook msi ex623 , with tool Chicony Firmware Tool v.3.0.2 -, firmware update CKF7010 firmware 6322."

1. With this information we can search MSI's support website for information regarding the "EX623" laptop, which we find at https://msi.com/Laptop/EX623.html
2. From this page, we can click "Service" to be taken to the support pages specific to this laptop, and click "Firmware" to see any firmware associated with this laptop that they offer. This brings us to https://msi.com/Laptop/support/EX623#down-firmware
3. On this page we find that MSI offers a firmware update for the camera titled "NB Camera/VGA/EC Firmware".

If the Alex is still having this issue, or if any others make the same mistake, I hope this will prove useful in recovering the functionality of their laptop's webcam.