# Camera app not detecting camera after driver installation

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, camera

Before I installed camera drivers the camera app was working just fine but after installing any app that uses my camera (except skype though) cannnot detect it.

The camera is integrated in my laptop (asus G73JH-B1). The camera works fine with my camera software.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: If it was working why did you install the drivers?  The problem clearly is those drivers.  I am shocked Skype works it normally does not in a situation like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam)

Comment: Roll back drivers. Do you know how to do it?