# Camera doesn't show video in Discord/Skype

Tags: windows-10, video, skype, webcam, camera

My girlfriend's camera hasn't been working for a while. It worked fine before, but now it doesn't show the video anymore, at least in Skype/Discord. In the Camera app from Windows 10 it works perfectly fine. In Skype it before didn't even let her start the video call, since a Windows update it lets her start it, but the video simply doesn't show up. In Discord it shows a loading circle that never finishes loading.

The correct cameras are recognized and selected by each software.

We tried looking in varius settings of Discord, Skype and Windows 10 itself to see if there were any permissions missing, there weren't. We're really at a loss of ideas. The issue remains with both her inbuilt Laptop camera and an external camera.

OS is Windows 10 and her laptop is a Lenovo.

Comment: When I had this [exact problem](https://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam) it was a USB driver that would not allow any WIn32 application access to the camera.  Update your question to indicate if the UWP Camera application works.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not just the external USB camera, though, the inbuilt laptop camera is just as affected.

Comment: The built-in camera more than likely is simply a USB device.  "it shows a loading circle that never finishes" is more or less the exact behavior I encountered with Skype in Nov 2017.  Please indicate what updates have recently been installed.  You also need to indicate which version of Windows 10 you are running.  You also need to indicate, some specific information, about both of the cameras.  Please provide all information as an edit to your question instead of a comment.  What version of Skype are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm unfortunately not a professional so if you can tell me how to get these informations that would be great, if not I'll see to find them myself tomorrow as it is too late for me right now. Thank you so far either way, though, I'll look into giving more detailed information ASAP!

Comment: I cannot help if you cannot determine which version of Skype you are using.  The information I requested does not take a professional to determine.  However, I won't be able to help or answer this question, without the information