# Windows 10 Built-in microphone not detected

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, thinkpad, microphone

I have a brand-new Lenovo ThinkPad P15s Gen 1, and Zoom was saying no microphone was detected. My Windows settings also say no input device is detected. When I run the audio troubleshooter, Windows says that no audio device is plugged in.

I suspect that this is due to some hardware updates which were issued recently since my microphone was working fine until I installed these recent updates:

## Quality Updates (8):

[image: updates 1]

## Driver Updates (31):

[image: driver 2]

[image: updates 3]

[image: updates 4]

## 1 failed Driver Update and Definition Updates (8):

[image: updates 5]

## Other Updates (2):

[image: updates 6]

---

And if I open Camera and try to record a video, I get the following error:

[image: camera error]

---

I'm not sure if I should uninstall any updates and which ones to uninstall, or if I should contact Lenovo support.

What should I do about this? I'm quite sure my laptop has a microphone built-in.

Comment: If you launch the Camera application is your device detected?

Comment: @Ramhound I get an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJjGi.png

Comment: Go to the Lenovo Support site for your model, and get System Update. Download it, install it and run it (it lives in Control Panel). See if it can update your drivers.

Comment: Uninstall all Lenovo software.  You likely have some useless Lenovo USB driver installed that is interfering.  I know what I am talking about had a similar issue awhile ago [here](https://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam)

Comment: I understand about the USB driver. I would be careful uninstalling ALL Lenovo software. It has been a couple of decades since we had to do that.

Comment: Also check your device manager for any devices with a \!/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I should uninstall any updates and which ones to
> uninstall, or if I should contact Lenovo support.

[Go to the Lenovo Support site for your model, and get the System Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p15s-type-20t4-20t5/20t4/20t40004uk/pf2bryw8/downloads/automatic-driver-update). Download it, install it and run it (it lives in Control Panel).

That should solve your issue.