# HP Webcam a127c driver

Tags: webcam

Does anybody know where I can download a driver for the HP Webcam a127c all-in-one? The HP drivers site does not list the camera/webcam. (HP support is unreachable - I'll never buy an HP again.) The generic USB Video Driver is working but I need the mfg driver to troubleshoot a Zoom Enable Camera problem.

System Info, Components, Problem Devices reports: Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed) USB\VID_0000&PID_0002\5&14F92505&0&7 43

Comment: What make is your webcam?

Comment: I dont know why HP would bother to make a driver for this cam.  That is probably why you don't see a driver on the site.  The generic USB is all the driver they need.. I personally wouldn't install their driver anyway.  It would be like installing a POS bloatware driver for a 2 button USB mouse.  Use the windows camera application, get it working.. then go to zoom.  If I insult, please forgive me ahead of time.  I wrote device drivers from win3.1/dos to windows 7.

Comment: Oh.. and hate HP for outsourcing all of their technical labor from Oregon to a country they are not located in.  Not for this.

Comment: The camera is a built-in HP. 

I need another driver to satisfy Zoom support. The camera is working fine but Zoom cannot Enable Video during a meeting. I guess I uncovered a data-dependent bug and they are wating to try another driver.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'd be OK with support from Mars at this point - no way to contact them at all.

Comment: Try this one:   https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-pavilion-27-a100-all-in-one-desktop-pc-series/12079711/model/12740569/swItemId/cp-182011-2    and for all drivers   https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-27-a100-all-in-one-desktop-pc-series/12079711/model/12740569

Comment: @john The driver site does not have an item for the camera I could find. The camera is not an IR version, but the standard webcam video.

Comment: Is there a way to discover the webcam make/model?

Comment: You should indicate to Zoom that the driver they are suggesting you use does not exist.  After you indicate the driver they want you to install does not exist, ask for a supervisor, elevated the problem to the next level support technician.

Comment: System Info, Components, Problem Devices reports:
Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed) USB\VID_0000&PID_0002\5&14F92505&0&7 43

Comment: @Ramhound I'm already up to the first developer level. Just trying to play along with the elimination game. I'm pretty sure the driver isn't the problem as the camera works fine in all but the case of clicking Enable Video when joining a meeting.

Comment: If you want real help with the Zoom problem we probably can help.  Make sure you don't have any third-party USB drives.  [It can cause some weird issues with webcams](https://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam)

Comment: @Ramhound At Start Video I am getting a message that the video failed to start and to connect to a different video camera - I only have one camera. Using the Zoom Test meeting I can click several more times on Start and it eventually works - very strange. I installed a trace version and the have the logs. One of those issues only a reinstall of the OS will fix I'm afraid.

Comment: "One of those issues only a reinstall" - Who told you this?  I was once told by Ubisoft support to reinstall Windows to fix a problem launching, a game by Ubisoft, when I researched the problem I discovered it was a common problem.  I would have reinstalled Windows for no reason if I listen to them.  The only time I have found, where the only solution to the problem is to reinstall Windows, is when Windows cannot boot due to a failed HDD.

Comment: One other thing to try.. see if Snap supports your cam, if it does.. you can use "snap" as your camera and turn the filters off.  This might be another way to get it working.

Comment: Oh.. and @Ramhound , your post is golden and should be read by all.  Support is notorious for "reinstalling windows" when they don't know WTF is not working.  I am glad you posted this.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Sadly, there are a handful of users in this community, who jumped at the chance to make that suggestion. The problem with that suggestion is any chance to diagnose the problem is lost, when a repair install is performed, impossible to look at logs when that solution is performed.  **Sure; It solves the problem but it's a boring solution.**

Comment: I am betting that you have a hardware issue.  Funny that [HP Support](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Fix-for-Unknown-USB-Device-Device-Descriptor-Request-Failed/td-p/5973953) shows this as solved but CLEARLY IS NOT SOLVED.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The Device Descriptor problem is probably not with the camera as it is working fine. I'll look into Snap.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree on the repair install issue. If I was at work a re-image is easy, not so much on my home consumer PC.