# Very, very slow file transfer/write/delete speeds on a Gen 4 NVME SSD in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, 7-zip

On the gneeric unzip functionality offered by Windows 10, I'm looking at horrendous unzip speeds of 1-3mb/s on average, as low as 300kb/s.

7Zip Alleviates this a little, boosting to 100-300 mb/s.

Normal file transfers (which can only be handled by Windows FS itself) is laughably slow, usaully capping at 10-100+mb/s.

What gives? I use a brand new Gen 4 NVME SSD that when benchmarked on CrystalDiskInfo, caps at close to 5000mb/s R/W speeds:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv1uZ.png]

I switched to a slower 500mb/s SATA SSD for testing and got the same results above. It's as if the speeds advertised never ever show up in real life scenarios.

Just curious, am I misunderstanding something about how R/W speeds work in WIndows 10 and/or SSDs? This is on a fresh install of Windows 10 on a gaming desktop, zero bloatware aside from Asus stuff (AI suite etc)

Comment: [I once had a USB problem, nobody could figure it what caused the problem, come to find it was caused by the AI Suite.  Get rid of that worthless piece of software.](https://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam)

Comment: How do you know which percentage is actual unzip speeds? IOW if Windows is dead slow in unzipping would that not greatly influence your measurements?