# Gigabyte B760 Gaming A AX motherboard - USB not charging

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-supply

The USBs of the Gigabyte B760 motherboard only charge the connected iPad when the computer is powered off (and also not always). When powered on, it does not charge.

I found the Gigabyte on-off charge page:
https://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm

But when I click download driver and enter the motherboard specs in the dropdown, no on-off charge driver is listed.

The iPad is connected to the ports located on the back of the computer, so to the motherboard directly. But also the USB (C) ports on the top of the case do not charge.

Any idea how I can make the USB ports always charge?

Ports used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

USB port connector used:

[image]

Comment: I should warn you about those USB drivers.  In the past they caused significant issues [in other ways](https://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam). They also shouldn't be required.  You have a Gigabyte B760 but which port are you using?

Comment: Any port. None charge the iPad (or earpods) when computer is on.

Comment: Let me ask a more basic question, snce "any port", does not answer my question.  Is the port you are using connected to the red `ON/OFF Charge USB Port` USB header on your motherboard.  *Most certainly the corresponding USB port would be on your case NOT your motherboard.* [Edit] your question with as much detail as possible.

Comment: @ramhound I mean the USB ports on the motherboard itself, on the backside of the computer. None of these ports charge the iPad while the computer is on. And they do infrequently charge when the computer is off.

Comment: You’re not using the correct port. The port you’re referencing is a header, which requires a port on a case, so I go back to my original question. Do you have a cable connected to the *ON/OFF Charge USB Port* on your motherboard?

Comment: @Ramhound Added more text and pictures. Hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: I can't determine the answer to my question, you will have to look and simply answer this very basic question, "do you have a USB port connected to the red ON/OFF Charge USB header on the motherboard?"

Comment: @Ramhound added a picture of the motherboard with an arrow to which usb connecter is used. Please see the motherboard website below, i don't think it has a red USB socket. Agree?
https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B760-GAMING-X-AX-rev-1x

Comment: Based on the information you provided.  Your motherboard does NOT have a `ON/OFF Charge USB Port`, so the expected behavior you were expecting, is simply not possible with the hardware you have. While your motherboard does have a red USB port, it's to indicate that the port is a USB 3.2 Gen 2 port, it also isn't a header but part of back panel I/O.

Answer (score -1):

> Any idea how I can make the USB ports always charge?

Your motherboard does not support `ON/OFF Charge USB Port`, which is required, to provide the ability to charge devices while your system is turned off.

Comment: There isn't enough information to diagnose the reason the devices sometimes are not charging. I see that has a secondary question, to the primary question, that was about the ability to charge devices while the system is turned off.

Comment: Yes it is very weird. An iPad for example, is always connected via USB. Each morning it is full. When i start using it icm with DUET Display as additional monitor, it stops charging. After a few hours it is empty. Next morning, full again.

Comment: @Peps - If the device is charging with your system turned off, then I am confused, by your question since you indicated devices were NOT being charged with the machine turned off.